# javascript how to run the same function onLoad and onChange

Tags: javascript, forms, select, onload, onchange

I have a form that has many select menus, most of them are Yes/No and depending on the selected option, I display/hide some advanced options. One of the select menus is the following:

```
<td><%= f.select :CBIAvailable, ['Yes' , 'No'],{}, {:id=>"cbi_available_id", :class=>"cbi_available_class", :onChange=>"showHideOptions('cbi_available_id','cbi_options_id')", :onLoad=>"showHideOptions('cbi_available_id','cbi_options_id')"} %></td>
```

When I change from 'Yes' to 'No' or the opposite, showHideOptions javascript functions is called properly, but I can't have that function to be called when I reload the form.

Anyone can tell me what am I dong wrong?

Thanks

UPDATE

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showHideOptions(selectorId,optionsId) {
  if (document.getElementById) {
    var selector = document.getElementById(selectorId);
    var options = document.getElementById(optionsId);
    if (selector.value == 'Yes') {
        options.style.display = 'block';
        return false;
    } else {
      options.style.display = 'none';
        return false;
    }
}

window.onLoad = showHideOptions('cbi_available_id','cbi_options_id');
```

Comment: I don't understand.  Onload gets called when the form is (re)loaded.  What were you expecting?

Comment: in my case, :CBIAvailable = 'No', so I expect showHideOptions function to execute when I reload the form and it should display the relevant options for 'No', but in fact the form reloads with the options for 'Yes'. When I change the select menu to 'No', it works fine, and when I change it back to 'No' it works as well. The problem is it does not display the right options onload

Answer (score 4):

```
function yourFunction(){

    //get that select element and evaluate value
    //do you change stuff here
}

window.onload = yourFunction;   //this gets fired on load

//"select" is your element, 
//fetched by methods like document.getElementById();

select.onchange = yourFunction; //this gets fired on change

//you can also use attachEvent (IE) or addEventListener (Others)
```

---

here's [a working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fskreuz/bAH9Y/):

```
<select id="testSelect">
    <option value="yes">YES</option>
    <option value="no">NO</option>
</select>​​​​​

function getOption() {
    alert('foo');
}

var select = document.getElementById('testSelect');
select.onchange = getOption;
window.onload = getOption;
```

​

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I updated my question above with the changes you proposed, but it still does not work fine when I reload the form. It does work fine when I change the selected option from 'Yes' to 'No' and the opposite.

Comment: Still does not work. In fact, with the original syntax, the function does fire onload (I tested by adding a document.wrtie inside the function) but it does not do the rest like when I select 'Yes' or 'No'

Comment: Thanks Joseph for your efforts. Much appreciated. Your demo definitely works, and that's how I'd like my script to work, but my if (selector.value == 'Yes') test above is still failing onLoad, even though it works fine onChange

Comment: I added alert(selectorId);alert(selector.value); at the beginning of my script and both of them fire onChange but only the 1st one fires onLoad. Very strange!

Comment: I finally figured out how to solve my problem. I had to put the window.onload line in a <script></script> section at the bottom of the file, after the form. I guess that way window.onload is executed after the form loads and therefore works fine. When window.onload is in a <script></script> section at the top of the file, document.getElementById(selectorId) points to null and therefore has no value to test against.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen when you receive postback from your remote server and your response doesn't have `<script type="javascript">... yourfunction()...</script>`.

Each time you get new response you should send script and exacute it or append to your html element approciate event handler.

Another solution is to use jQuery and use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event. This event attach dynamically behaviour to your html. **I strongly recommend you to use jQuery** with live because this library is one of most used libraries in production environment.

**Edit**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showHideOptions(id1,id2){
    //Your code
}
$(document).ready(function() {
   //This function waits for DOM load
   //execute your function for first time
   showHideOptions('cbi_available_id','cbi_options_id');
   //This selector you have to modify or show us generated html to
   // choose the best selector for this purpose
   $('.cbi_available_class').live('change',function(){
        //This will fire change event of html class="cbi_available_class"
        showHideOptions('cbi_available_id','cbi_options_id');
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks r.piesnikowski.
I do have
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showHideOptions(selectorId,optionsId) {
...
}
</script>
Can you please help with a sample jQuery script that uses /live()?

Comment: Note that Jquery live() was deprecated in JQuery 1.7 and removed from 1.9